# How to generate HBase java Put class from String Array?

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I am newbie on Java 8 lambda and stream programming. This is simple source which generate HBase Put class from String array.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
list.add("1," + "colFamily" + ",a,1");
list.add("2," + "colFamily" + ",a,2");
list.add("3," + "colFamily" + ",a,3");
list.add("4," + "colFamily" + ",a,4");
list.add("5," + "colFamily" + ",a,5");

for (int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++) {
  String[] cells = list.get(i).split(",");

  Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(cells[0]));
  put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(cells[1]),Bytes.toBytes(cells[2]),Bytes.toBytes(cells[3]));

System.out.println(put);
```

Results are generated correctly like below,

```
{"totalColumns":1,"row":"1","families":{"colFamily":[{"qualifier":"a","vlen":1,"tag":[],"timestamp":9223372036854775807}]}}
{"totalColumns":1,"row":"2","families":{"colFamily":[{"qualifier":"a","vlen":1,"tag":[],"timestamp":9223372036854775807}]}}
{"totalColumns":1,"row":"3","families":{"colFamily":[{"qualifier":"a","vlen":1,"tag":[],"timestamp":9223372036854775807}]}}
{"totalColumns":1,"row":"4","families":{"colFamily":[{"qualifier":"a","vlen":1,"tag":[],"timestamp":9223372036854775807}]}}
{"totalColumns":1,"row":"5","families":{"colFamily":[{"qualifier":"a","vlen":1,"tag":[],"timestamp":9223372036854775807}]}}
```

But by using Java 8 stream, I failed to generate the same results, below is the codes.

```
System.out.println(list.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(l -> new Put(Bytes.toBytes(l)), Collectors.toList())));
```

But definitely the above code brings the wrong results.

```
[{"totalColumns":0,"row":"1,colFamily,a,1","families":{}}, {"totalColumns":0,"row":"2,colFamily,a,2","families":{}}, {"totalColumns":0,"row":"3,colFamily,a,3","families":{}}, {"totalColumns":0,"row":"4,colFamily,a,4","families":{}}, {"totalColumns":0,"row":"5,colFamily,a,5","families":{}}]
```

I have no idea how to split comma-seperated-Strings to String array using java 8 stream function.

Comment: Hi Joseph - may I offer you a few posting tips? I am a volunteer editor, and most of my time on Stack Overflow is spent showing people how to ask good questions, or editing their questions into shape. We really like succinct questions here, so if you could omit the following, that would be great. (a) how much you need a reply, (b) how long you have been stuck, (c) that you (deeply) appreciate replies, (d) the sending of (kind/best) regards, (e) any form of txtspk, such as "pls". This will save a great deal of volunteer time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
list
.stream()
.map(s -> s.split(","))
.map(cells -> {
    Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(cells[0]));
    put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(cells[1]), Bytes.toBytes(cells[2]), Bytes.toBytes(cells[3]));
    return put;
})
.forEach(System.out::println) // or .collect to list
```